# LNK2005 error with multiple translation units

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I'm writing a small arbitrary-precision arithmetic library, and I have encountered a problem:

I have exception class, derived from `std::exception`, in my *exception.h* and *exception.cpp*. *Exception.h* is included by *vector.h*, and *vector.h*, in turn, is included by my_long.h.

So the problem is: when I'm including my_long.h in *main.cpp* and my_long.cpp, I'm getting a redefinition linker error `LNK2005` for all functions in my exception class, which is quite logical, because I'm including this class in two different translation units and then trying to link them together.

Is there any possible workarounds, or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide exception.h and .cpp and the exact error messages?

Comment: Header files should only contain _declarations_, not _definitions_. If the `exception.h` file isn't do big, you should edit your question to include it. Also add the error messages verbatim to your question.

Comment: Perhaps, you class definition depends on some macros, which are defined in some translation units, but not defined in others. Please show some code and the exact error messages.

Comment: Use the `inline` keyword for function definitions in the .h file.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices. You can either mark all of the functions in my_long.h as inline, which allows multiple identical definitions, or you can move the function definitions to my_long.cpp and put forward declarations for them in my_long.h.

Typically, to keep the header file readable, you should do the second except for very small functions.